# How do is structure my files right, when I write code for linux and windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, compiler-errors, cross-platform

I am currently not sure how I should seperate my code best. I currently programming a software which should run on Linux and Windows. So I decided to put all OS-secificstuff in thier own folder/files.

For example
This is the header file:

```
#ifdef __linux__
#include <unistd.h>
#elif _WIN64
#include <Windows.h>
#endif
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


#pragma once

class SystemTools
{
public:
    // Delay in secounds until the programm continues
    static void sleep(int delay);


private:
};
```

and the OS specific implementation is in the linux/windows folder
Linux:

```
#ifdef __linux__
#include "../SystemTools.h"

void SystemTools::sleep(int delay)
{
    usleep(delay*1000000);
}
#endif
```

Windows:

```
#ifdef _WIN64
#include "../SystemTools.h"

void SystemTools::sleep(int delay)
{
    Sleep(delay*1000);
}

#endif
```

This works and I have no problems so far, but when I now have methods which don´t need any OS specific code I created an additional folder "Generic" so I can write the code in there and don´t have to mantain the same code in the linux and windows file. For example like that:

Generic:

```
#include "../SystemTools.h"

void SystemTools::sleepMin(int delay)
{
    sleep(delay*60);
}

#endif
```

That still workes on Linux but not on Windows (no error but does not compile, used codeblockes for that on windows). So how do I organize my code correct? Should I use only one file with ifdef even it that gets very fast ugly?

(compiler Linux: g++, Windows: should be MinGW)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I'd suggest you to use the most recent of C++ (C++20 or so) on your project. This way, we can abstract many OS related calls (like threading, synchronization, random numbers and etc).

That means, you won't really need to use too many of OS specific APIs. IE: C++11 and earlier already have a standard way to sleep:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for

In the end, if you really need to call OS specific things on windows and on linux, using a library could be interesting and pay attention that windows C++ compiler (visual studio) really like to use 'pre compiled headers' so, it's interesting to have a single header file where all windows specific headers can be included.

Basically that. You can have a standard Cmake or makefile for your linux build and use .sln Visual Studio project to build it to windows.

That's the way I would do that

Comment: Multi-threading was added to C++ in C++11. No need to hold out for C++20.

Comment: I am not sure which C++ version I have but i got the standard version of g++ in the Fedora 34 release. If I did not made it clear, I only use one header file but multiple cpp files for the diffrend OS. I mostly develop on Linux and I don´t know why but Visual Studio cause always some kinds of problems when using it and the license is not that cheap. I would love to build the program on Linux for windows too but it seems that it won´t work since it has problems with the Windows SendInput (mostly with the Input )

Comment: A library  would be a good idea but I did not found a good one so far and getting for ever minor function a new library is not very practical for me. Thank you for you answer anyway.